# When I update my Avatar picture, it changes all users picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, avatar

I seem to be making an error in my code. I've been looking at two of my past projects and in one I have a pictures table to associate a picture_id with a user but on a different project it wasn't even required and I forgot how I did it. Any advice in my code for improvement and reason of error will be appreciated, Thank you in advance.

**Schema**

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.integer  "zip_code"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "profile_id"
    t.string   "background_file_name"
    t.string   "background_content_type"
    t.integer  "background_file_size"
    t.datetime "background_updated_at"
    t.string   "slug"
  end
```

**User/show**

```
<div id="profile_to">
 <div class="profile_background_picture">
  <%= image_tag current_user.background.url(:medium) %>
 </div>
 <div class="profile_picture">
  <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
 </div>
</div>
```

**User/index**

```
<% if current_user %>
 <div id="login_top">
  <a href="/"><p class="logo">Trend</p></a>
  <nav>
   <div class="loginout">
    <%= link_to ("LOGOUT"), "/sessions/new",method: :delete %>
   </div>
   <div class="user-links">
    <a href="/users/<%= current_user.id %>">
     <% if current_user.user_name.present? %>
      <%= link_to current_user.user_name, user_path(current_user) %>
     <% else %>
      <%= current_user.first_name %>
     <% end %>
    </a>
    &nbsp;<b class="size">|</b>&nbsp;
    <a href="">Settings</a>
    &nbsp;<b class="size">|</b>&nbsp;
   </div>
   <% if current_user.avatar.present? %>
    <div class="circular">
     <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
    </div>
   <% else %>     
   <% end %>
  </nav>
 </div> 
<% end %>

<%= form_for current_user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <p class="editpage">Profile Picture: <%= f.file_field :avatar %></p>
  <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

**User Model**

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
 :medium => "200x200>",
 :small => "120x120#",
 :thumb => "75x75#",
 :default_url => "http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png"
}

validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

has_attached_file :background, :styles => {
 :medium => "200x200>",
 :small => "120x120#",
 :thumb => "75x75#",
 :default_url => "http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png"
}

validates_attachment_content_type :background, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

For further information, please feel free to ask. Again, thank you for all your help and explanation to my error.

**User Controller**

```
def index
 @user = User.new
 @users = User.all
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
 if @user.save
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  cookies[:user_id] = @user.id
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully Registerd"
  redirect_to "/"
 else
  flash[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages
  redirect_to "/"
 end
end

def new
 @user = User.new
end

def edit
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 current_user
end

def show
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 current_user
end

def update
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
   flash[:notice] = "You have successfully update your information"
   redirect_to "/"
 end
end

def destroy
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @user.destroy
end

private

def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:background, :username_or_email, :first_name,  :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_name, :female, :male, :avatar, :gender, :zip_code, :birthdate)
end
```

Comment: Maybe you should copy some code from your controller too?

Comment: @Liyali I've added my user controller as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach has a [pungent code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell); I do not see any reason for your `User` model to have a `t.integer  "user_id"` column, especially when you've set the asset directly on the user model.  This is also a poor, and brittle, approach as you've lumped images with the `User`.

When building a feature like this, it's good to attempt normalising your domain model, and one approach would be to have two tables - `users` and `user_avatars`. This way, the `user_avatars` table can have a `user_id` column to be used as a foreign key.  a `User` instance with `has_one :avatar_image, class_name: "::UserAvatar"` and `UserAvatar` will `belong_to :user`.

This will allow your `user` instance (i.e. where `user = User.new`; I'm simply showing that it's an instance of the `User` klass) to be able to call `user.avatar_image`; and if you had a `has_attached_file :avatar` declaration on the `UserAvatar`, you'll be able to fetch that via `user.avatar_image.avatar.url(:thumb)`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'll be reformatting the way my tables look in order to hopefully avoid a bigger problem for the future. First time hearing about "Code Smell". Thanks for that and I have a final question. Should I also make a model such as user_profiles in order to put a user profile information there or keep it together with the user model? Thanks again for your explanation.

Comment: Chances are, a user will have a single profile (but potentially multiple avatar images? Depends on your use case) and a single avatar, which could be part of their profile.  Good case for User `has_one` :profile.  It doesn't hurt to keep these separate from the User itself.